# The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I know there are similar questions on stackoverflow - and I looked through them and think my issue is somewhat similar, but haven't been able to find a solution by looking at any of these other questions/answers.
I'm getting the error when attempting to execute the following code:

```
Private Sub btnReserve_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReserve.Click
    ' Check that the room is still available.
    Dim dbCheckOccupants As New pbu_housingEntities
    Dim hall As String = CStr(Session("hall"))
    Dim room As String = CStr(Session("room"))
    Dim checkOccupants = From p In dbCheckOccupants.Rooms _
                         Let building_id = p.Building1.id _
                         Where p.building_name = hall _
                         Where p.room1 = room _
                         Select p.current_occupancy, p.max_occupancy, p.id, building_id
    If checkOccupants.First.current_occupancy >= checkOccupants.First.max_occupancy Then
        ' If it isn't available, let student know.
        lblResult.Text = "Sorry, this room is now fully occupied. Please choose another room."
    Else
        ' If it is available, add the student to the room.
        Dim AddOccupant As New pbu_housingEntities
        Dim Occupant As New Resident
        Dim gender As String = CStr(Session("gender"))
        Dim person_name As String = CStr(Session("person_name"))
        Dim class_level As String = CStr(Session("class_level"))
        Dim semester As String = CStr(Session("term"))
        Dim people_code_id As String = CStr(Session("people_code_id"))
        Dim first_name As String = CStr(Session("first_name"))
        Dim last_name As String = CStr(Session("last_name"))
        Dim building_id As String = checkOccupants.First.building_id
        Dim room_id As String = checkOccupants.First.id
        Occupant.building = building_id
        Occupant.room = room_id
        Occupant.gender = gender
        Occupant.person_name = person_name
        Occupant.class_level = class_level
        Occupant.semester = semester
        Occupant.people_code_id = people_code_id
        Occupant.create_date = Date.Now
        Occupant.first_name = first_name
        Occupant.last_name = last_name
        AddOccupant.Residents.AddObject(Occupant)
        AddOccupant.SaveChanges()
        ' Increment the number of occupants in the room.
        Dim UpdateRoomOccupancy As New pbu_housingEntities
        Dim UpdateOccupancy = (From p In UpdateRoomOccupancy.Rooms _
                               Where p.building_name = hall _
                               Where p.room1 = room _
                               Select p).First
        UpdateOccupancy.current_occupancy = UpdateOccupancy.current_occupancy + 1
        UpdateRoomOccupancy.SaveChanges()
        ' Add the student to a bed.
        Dim AddBed As New pbu_housingEntities
        Dim UpdateBed = From p In AddBed.Beds _
                        Where p.building = building_id _
                        Where p.room = room_id _
                        Where p.occupant = "" _
                        Select p

        ' Get the student's ID from the residency table.
        Dim GetID = From p In AddBed.Residents _
                    Where p.people_code_id = people_code_id _
                    Order By p.id Descending _
                    Select p

        Dim myID As String = GetID.First.id.ToString

        UpdateBed.First.occupant = myID
        AddBed.SaveChanges()
        lblResult.Text = "Success! You have successfully requested residency in this room!"
    End If
End Sub
```

It is catching an error on this line:

```
Dim myID As String = GetID.First.id.ToString
```

As far as I can tell I'm not using multiple contexts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see exactly why you could get an exception on the line you indicated but the code has in my opinion two flaws: You instantiate 4 different contexts in this method (although I do not see that you mix objects from those contexts) and you don't dispose any of them. (The database context references an external resource (database connection) which to dispose explicitely is a good practice.)

Try to rewrite it so that you have only one context `dbContext`, `SaveChanges` is only called once and this single context is disposed at the end of the method (through the `Using` block):

```
Private Sub btnReserve_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReserve.Click
    ' Check that the room is still available.
    Using (dbContext As pbu_housingEntities = New pbu_housingEntities)
        ' Check that the room is still available.
        Dim hall As String = CStr(Session("hall"))
        Dim room As String = CStr(Session("room"))
        Dim checkOccupants = From p In dbContext.Rooms _
                             Let building_id = p.Building1.id _
                             Where p.building_name = hall _
                             Where p.room1 = room _
                             Select p.current_occupancy, p.max_occupancy, p.id, building_id
        If checkOccupants.First.current_occupancy >= checkOccupants.First.max_occupancy Then
            ' If it isn't available, let student know.
            lblResult.Text = "Sorry, this room is now fully occupied. Please choose another room."
        Else
            ' If it is available, add the student to the room.
            Dim Occupant As New Resident
            Dim gender As String = CStr(Session("gender"))
            Dim person_name As String = CStr(Session("person_name"))
            Dim class_level As String = CStr(Session("class_level"))
            Dim semester As String = CStr(Session("term"))
            Dim people_code_id As String = CStr(Session("people_code_id"))
            Dim first_name As String = CStr(Session("first_name"))
            Dim last_name As String = CStr(Session("last_name"))
            Dim building_id As String = checkOccupants.First.building_id
            Dim room_id As String = checkOccupants.First.id
            Occupant.building = building_id
            Occupant.room = room_id
            Occupant.gender = gender
            Occupant.person_name = person_name
            Occupant.class_level = class_level
            Occupant.semester = semester
            Occupant.people_code_id = people_code_id
            Occupant.create_date = Date.Now
            Occupant.first_name = first_name
            Occupant.last_name = last_name
            dbContext.Residents.AddObject(Occupant)

            ' Increment the number of occupants in the room.
            Dim UpdateOccupancy = (From p In dbContext.Rooms _
                                   Where p.building_name = hall _
                                   Where p.room1 = room _
                                   Select p).First
            UpdateOccupancy.current_occupancy = UpdateOccupancy.current_occupancy + 1

            ' Add the student to a bed.
            Dim UpdateBed = From p In dbContext.Beds _
                            Where p.building = building_id _
                            Where p.room = room_id _
                            Where p.occupant = "" _
                            Select p

            ' Get the student's ID from the residency table.
            Dim GetID = From p In dbContext.Residents _
                        Where p.people_code_id = people_code_id _
                        Order By p.id Descending _
                        Select p

            Dim myID As String = GetID.First.id.ToString

            UpdateBed.First.occupant = myID

            dbContext.SaveChanges()

            lblResult.Text = "Success! You have successfully requested residency in this room!"
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

With a little luck the error disappears and the code is still doing the same as before.

**Edit**

I just add quickly a general note: Perhaps you have the (wrong) idea that you need a new context for every query, Insert or Delete operation. That's not the case and actually bad practice with a high risk to mix objects among different contexts. In most situations you can follow a standard pattern in your methods like so:

```
' Create one single context
Using (dbContext As pbu_housingEntities = New pbu_housingEntities)

    ' Use here this dbContext for as many queries, Adds, Deletes and Changes
    ' as you need and like

    ' Save ALL Adds, Deletes and Changes you have done in this block
    dbContext.SaveChanges()

End Using
```

It's also important to know that SaveChanges will execute a database transaction, so it's an All-Or-Nothing operation. I could imagine that this is also important in your method. For instance the two operations you have commented with `Increment the number of occupants in the room.` and `Add the student to a bed.`, shouldn't they happen either both or none of them to avoid an inconsistent state in the database? With your different contexts it could be possible that the first operation succeeds but the second fails, leaving your data in an inconsistent state in the DB.

Comment: WOW! Thanks! This is hugely helpful. I think my understanding of this topic just expanded by 2x. I'm going to try rewriting the code as you suggested and will let you know how it goes. :)

Comment: Takes a little while to get used to it all but will soon start to make more sense!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you not get the ID in one call?

```
Dim MyID = (From p In AddBed.Residents _
                    Where p.people_code_id = people_code_id _
                    Order By p.id Descending _
                    Select p.id).SingleOrDefault()
```

You are calling multiple instances of the context by the looks of it. Try the using block as the other answer recommends